# Creating a React Native App to Fetch and Play HTML5 Games from Web/API paid or free

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, webview, 2d-games

I'm working on a React Native project, and I'd like to build an app that allows users to play HTML5 games fetched from the web or an API. I'm relatively new to React Native, and I'm seeking guidance on the best approach to implement this feature.

Specifically, I'm interested in:

Fetching HTML5 games from a web source or API.
Displaying these games within my React Native app.
Allowing users to play these games seamlessly.
If anyone has experience with similar implementations or can provide guidance on the necessary libraries, best practices, or sample code snippets, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) to show the game directly through url.

If you want to communicate with web like need to run any js code use prop
`injectedJavaScript` and you can listen to response from web through `onMessage`

There is multiple ways to inject JavaScript [visit](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/6960a1903c3c32e1e77be11e6370f1c384ed7ee4/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascript)